# jQuery Flot - Display accurate values

Tags: jquery, tooltip, decimal, flot

I notice that jQuery Flot is rounding down the results.  But I want to show the actual decimal value for the result when you hover over the peaks and valleys in the tooltip. But not the x or y axis labels, but the graph result itself.

So instead of "44", I want "44.05".

Is there anything I can do to make that work? Everything I'm seeing is just for the axis labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool tip should allow you to do this - have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rnusy/

```
 var previousPoint = null;
        $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item){
            $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
            $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
            if (item) {
                if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex){
                    previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, y);
                                                    }
                    }
                else {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;
                    }

            });
```

Comment: change the toFixed(2) if you want more than two decimal places

Answer (score 1):

To show accurate values in the tooltip make this:

```
tooltipOpts: {
    content: "%s : %y.2",
}
```

Where "y" is your value and 2 is the number of decimal places.